# Problem with types when using react-bootstrap Button with react-router and typescript

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-bootstrap

I have created a simple react bootstrap card component which looks like that:

```
<Card className={` ${styles.stretchCard}`}>
  <Card.Body className='d-flex flex-column'>
    <Card.Title>{post.title}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text className='m-0'><span className={styles.dataTitle}>Author: </span>{post.author}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text ><span className={styles.dataTitle}>Published: </span>{post.publishedDate}</Card.Text>
    <Card.Text>{post.shortDescription}</Card.Text>
    <Button
      as={Link}
      to={`post/${post.id}`}
      className='align-self-start mt-auto'
    >
      Read more
    </Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

The component uses boostrap `Button` in which the `as` property is passed and it is a `react-router` `Link` component. Everything works just fine but after compiling the code I get the following error:

> Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & RefAttributes>' is not assignable to type '(ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & RefAttributes> & keyof IntrinsicElements) | undefined'.
> Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & RefAttributes>' is not assignable to type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & RefAttributes> & "symbol"'.
> Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & RefAttributes>' is not assignable to type '"symbol"'.
> 18 |               <Card.Text >Published: {post.publishedDate}</Card.Text>
> 19 |               <Card.Text>{post.shortDescription}</Card.Text>
> 20 |               <Button as={Link} to={`post/${post.id}`} className='align-self-start mt-auto'>Read more
> |                       ^^
> 21 |             </Card.Body>
> 22 |           
> 23 |

I was wondering whether I could cast the `Link` item with a specific type - if so what should it look like, because that is what I cannot figure out. I really would like to keep the type checking for the whole project so I do not want to cast as "any".

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but casting the `link` component to a `React.ComponentClass` when passing it to the **Button** component seems to solve the issue you have described.

Dropping this here for future refs.

```
import { Link, LinkProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

type CustomBootstrapLinkType = React.ComponentClass<LinkProps> & keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements

<Button
  variant="link"
  as={
    Link as unknown as CustomBootstrapLinkType
  }
  to={`post/${post.id}`}
>
    view more &gt;
</Button>
```